# How can I set Install4j variable from main class?

Tags: java, variables, install4j

I have a "Download File" action in the "Installer" step of Install4j. This action downloads a file and saves it to the installation directory. All of that works fine. However, the URL of the file to be downloaded is dependent upon user input. How can I set the URL to a variable (from my main class) that I can then use from within the download file action? I have only been able to find a way to *get* variables in the main class, but not *set* them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your "Download file" action, add a "Set a variable" action. In the action's configuration change the "Script" to return the desired URL string:

```
// Get some user input from some screen's input field.
String userInput = (String)context.getVariable("sometextbox");

// Call your custom code with user input and return a url
String url = com.mycompany.getDownloadFileUrl(userInput);

// Set it to the runtime variable.
return url;
```

Set the "Variable" property to a recognizable name.

Then, go back to your "Download file" action and click the arrow that appears if you click within the entry field for "URL".

Click insert runtime variable -> Bound variables and click the variable you created in the earlier step.

Comment: ohh hmm, i didn't know that I could call my code from the scripts. I was trying to do it the other way around (set the variable in my code). thanks; i'll go try it!!

Comment: To make your code accessible by install4j in the IDE and during the build, make sure you add entries for your jar files on the screen shown by clicking the "Installer" tab on the left and then Custom Code & Resources on the bottom tabs. More info here: http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/steps/installerGui/customCode.html